# React-Native Switch color of long press shadow

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an application with `react-native` version `0.57`. I'm using [`Switch`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch) for switch button. I used its props for customizing it, ***but*** the color of long press shadow is green and I don't know how I can change it.

[image]

When I long press the `Switch` key the appear shadow is green, how I can change its color?

Comment: You have to change the tint color in your android's `styles.xml`. The green is standard color for android. Add a new item `<item name="colorAccent">#0291C9</item>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this

```
tintColor="green"
```

Comment: The `tintColor` is deprecated, and the `tintColor` doesn't affect on thumb long press shadow. Also, I don't want it be green. I wanna it be in my color system. I cannot access to it.